# PC-24 has a cargo capacity of only 400 pounds?

Tags: cargo, pilatus-pc-24

I went to book a PC-24 with 3 passengers weighing a total of 450 pounds and 700 pounds of luggage for a total of 1,150 pounds. I thought this was doable because the payload capacity of a PC-24 is stated as 2,500 pounds. However, the operator came back and said I could only have 400 pounds of luggage. Nowhere could I find this limit in the specifications. Where is this limit defined?

Comment: Max payload is 2,500lbs but Min payload is 715lbs with full fuel. Please include the flight routing so we can have an idea of how much fuel is required. Also, will the flight have 1 or 2 pilots?

Comment: @MikeSowsun Aircraft payload does not include fuel. "Useful load" is the characteristic that includes fuel. The useful load of a PC-24 is 6880 pounds.

Comment: Yes, “payload” does not include fuel, but fuel required for the mission determines max payload. What is the flight routing you are planning?

Comment: I get you're sore that your project won't work, but you would benefit from finding the reasons why instead of just throwing tantrums and shooting messengers.  You demand that all airplane pax+cargo capacity assume full fuel.   That would unnecessarily limit the aircraft on shorter flights where full fuel is not required. What you don't understand is the rocket equation. It's an airplane not a car, fuel is a *significant* fraction of total weight.

Answer (score 5):

Payload is traded off against fuel, so the combined number is the limit.

The [PC24](https://www.pilatus-aircraft.com/en/fly/pc-24) has a useful load of 6679lb, consisting of 5964lb max usable fuel plus 715lb payload with full fuel. If the operator is allowing you 850lb, he is figuring 200lb for a single pilot (400lb for two pilots) and reserving 5629lb for fuel. This gives a 2000nm range at long range speed with reserves.

You don't get 2500lb payload AND full fuel. If you want to carry the maximum payload of 2500lb you have to cut fuel to 4179lb to stay below gross. This amount of fuel cuts range to about 1500nm. Is that how far you want to go?

Comment: ????? What ???? The stated payload of a PC-24 is 2,500 pounds, as it says in the question. The PC-24 is an EIGHT seat aircraft. That's in addition to the pilots.

Comment: @TylerDurden So look at the reference. The useful load is 6679 which counts both payload and fuel. You don't get 2500lb payload AND full fuel. If you want to carry the maximum payload of 2500lb you have to cut fuel to 4179lb to stay below gross. This amount of fuel cuts range to about 1500nm. Is that how far you want to go?

Comment: Payload includes cargo and people. It does not include fuel.

Comment: @TylerDurden. It would seem the sales pitch needs technical review.

Comment: @TylerDurden So look at the reference, do some math and get back to me. Max payload with full fuel is 715lb, not 2500lb. Again, if you want 2500lb payload you have to cut fuel. There is more than one constraint. This isn't that hard.

Answer (score 2):

Seems all the answers are missing the point.  The question was “why can’t you take more than 400 pounds of baggage and where is that listed?”  The max load in the cargo area is 400 pounds and that is in Section 2, “Limitations” of the AFM…  You are right that total payload is people, baggage, fuel, etc. However there are further limitations on how that can be carried, where on the aircraft that further limit the total number.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: aviation mission planning is complex.

### It's not rocket science. *Oh wait... it is!*

It's the Rocket Equation, actually.

The keystone fact you're missing is that cars weigh 3000 lbs and have 100 lb. of usable fuel, which is trivial, so you're used to dismissing fuel as a factor.  But on an airplane, **fuel is a huge part of total aircraft weight**, and has a huge effect on mission capability.  Further, **total weight has a huge impact on fuel consumption**, so you get into a vicious cycle where the weight of the fuel impacts the amount of fuel needed, **carrying more fuel burns more fuel** because of induced drag, and here we are at the ever-annoying exponentiality of the Rocket Equation.

As such, calculations are done to determine how much fuel to carry.  You need extra for surprises, but other than that, the less the better for efficiency.  *Unless* the price of fuel at airports differs enough to justify intentionally "tankering", and now we add *the dismal science* to the fray.

Suffice it to say there is no lack of complexity.

### Cargo capacity is impacted by fuel

The Wikipedia page stated a cargo capacity, and you took it on faith that it meant "with full fuel tanks".

Well, that would be a fairly ... crippling... way to rate an aircraft.  The reality of the Rocket Equation is that you can trade range for cargo capacity, and why shouldn't you if the airplane can handle it?

This results in a cargo rating which is, yeah, not at maximum range rating and vice versa.

Anyway, since you're not actually on a rocket,  your answer is "plan fuel stop(s)".  Or if impossible, get a bigger airplane.

Answer (score 0):

Maximum takeoff weight can be restricted by a variety of aircraft performance constraints -- short runway, sloped runway effects, warm or hot outside air temperature, nearby obstacles that need to be cleared and the combination of all of those. The lighter the aircraft, the better the performance.

Furthermore, for certification (=safety) reasons, most business jet takeoff performance calculations assume an engine loss just prior to liftoff and subsequent single engine climb performance to clear obstacles. All constraints must be met under that assumption. What airport are you planning to takeoff from?

Comment: I don't think the PC-24 performance calculations assume losing an engine after takeoff.

Comment: It'll still be climbing past 20,000 feet on one engine.